# ¿Como ingresar datos a un diccionario y calcular la media con ellas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como estan?

Estoy haciendo ejercicios de práctica para aprender Python (Ya que es mi primer lenguaje de programación).

**El ejercicio me pide lo siguiente:**

**A)** Crea un programa que permita introducir a un profesor las notas de sus estudiantes (máximo 10
estudiantes). Los datos se deberán almacenar en un diccionario como el siguiente:

```py
estudiantes = {
 "1": {
 "nombre": "Lorea",
 "nota": 8
 },
 "2": {
 "nombre": "Markel",
 "nota": "4.2"
 },
 "3": {
 "nombre": "Julen",
 "nota": 6.5
 }
}
```

**B)** Una vez introducidos todos los datos, el programa mostrará una lista con los nombres de los
estudiantes que han suspendido y otra con los que han aprobado. También calculará y mostrará
la nota media de la clase. **(AYUDA CON ESTE PUNTO)**

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Esto es lo que hice en el punto A (Siento que lo que hice en este punto se puede llegar a optimizar muchísimo, si alguien sabe cómo hacerlo me ayudaría un montón):

```py
lista = []
lista_nota = []
contador = 1

for i in range(1, 10 + 1):
    namee = input("Introduce nombre: ")
    nota = int(input("Introduce nota: "))
    print(' ')
    lista.append(namee)
    lista_nota.append(nota)

estudiantes = {
    "1": {
        "nombre": f"{lista[0]}",
        "nota": f"{lista_nota[0]}"
    },
    "2": {
        "nombre": f"{lista[1]}",
        "nota": f"{lista_nota[1]}"
    },
    "3": {
        "nombre": f"{lista[2]}",
        "nota": f"{lista_nota[2]}"
    },
    "4": {
        "nombre": f"{lista[3]}",
        "nota": f"{lista_nota[3]}"
    },
    "5": {
        "nombre": f"{lista[4]}",
        "nota": f"{lista_nota[4]}"
    },
    "6": {
        "nombre": f"{lista[5]}",
        "nota": f"{lista_nota[5]}"
    },
    "7": {
        "nombre": f"{lista[6]}",
        "nota": f"{lista_nota[6]}"
    },
    "8": {
        "nombre": f"{lista[7]}",
        "nota": f"{lista_nota[7]}"
    },
    "9": {
        "nombre": f"{lista[8]}",
        "nota": f"{lista_nota[8]}"
    },
    "10": {
        "nombre": f"{lista[9]}",
        "nota": f"{lista_nota[9]}"
    }
}

while contador <= 10:
    con_string = str(contador)
    print(str(contador), ": ", estudiantes[con_string]['nombre'], ", ", "Nota = ", estudiantes[con_string]['nota'])
    contador += 1
```

Y lo más importante, si me pueden ayudar con el punto **B**, ya que este directamente no sé como hacerlo.

Muchas gracias por leer, espero puedan ayudarme. Un saludo :D

Comment: Intenta hacer el segundo punto, si no adjuntas lo que has intentado no puedo ayudarte. Te doy una pista, intenta sacar el valor "nota" de cada alumno y los vas sumando en un ciclo `for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola espero no llegar tarde, te dejo la solución, suspendidos y aprobados puedes ponerle la restricción que quieras ya que en mi país es mayor a 10 xd, espero que te sirva bro, bendiciones.

```
n=1
estudiantes = {}

while(n<=10):
    nombre = input("Ingrese nombre: ")
    nota = int(input("Ingrese nota: "))
    print("\n")

    estudiantes[n] = {'nombre':nombre, 'nota':nota}
    n+=1

#Mostrando todos los estudiantes
print("Lista de todos los estudiantes de la clase")
for n,d in estudiantes.items():
    print(f"Nombre: {d['nombre']} Nota = {d['nota']}")


#mostrando los estudiantes suspendidos
print("\nEstudiantes Suspendidos")
for n,d in estudiantes.items():
    if(d['nota']<11):
        print(f"Nombre: {d['nombre']} Nota = {d['nota']}")

#mostrando los estudiantes aprobados
print("\nEstudiantes Aprobados")
for n,d in estudiantes.items():
    if(d['nota']>10):
        print(f"Nombre: {d['nombre']} Nota = {d['nota']}")

#Nota promedia de la clase
print("\nNota promedio de la clase")
nota = 0
for n,d in estudiantes.items():
    nota += d['nota'] # es igual a nota = nota + d['nota']
print(nota/len(estudiantes))
```

Comment: Me sirvió!! Mil gracias por la ayuda :D

Comment: Excelente ejemplo de las técnicas apropiadas para manejar listas.